# Convert html table to several div

Tags: html, gwt

I have this definition:

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="container" styleName="{style.itemcontainer}">
    <table style="width:100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td width="25px" valign="bottom">
            <b:Span ui:field="iconSpan" addStyleNames="{style.icon}"></b:Span>
        </td>

        <td width="60px">
            <span ui:field="valueLabel" class="{style.valueLabel}">0%</span>
        </td>

        <td width="24px" class="{style.selectedIcon}">
            <b:Icon ui:field="selectedIcon" type="BAR_CHART_O" visible="false"></b:Icon>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table> 

</g:HTMLPanel>
```

I would like to convet the html table in 3 div´s.

Could you help me?

Comment: Ever heard of "responsive design"? The idea, roughly, is to use percentage widths and float everything left. A better approach would be to use twitter bootstrap, which has css classes built in that define various widths that even appear differently on different device sizes.

Comment: Thanks Adam and sorry but my knowledge on design web are very basic. I´ll read about your comments

Answer (score 1):

Check out float and box model. You could make this simpler with css.

```
<div style="float:left">
   <b:Span ui:field="iconSpan" addStyleNames="{style.icon}"></b:Span>
</div>

<div style="float:left">
  <span ui:field="valueLabel" class="{style.valueLabel}">0%</span>
</div>

<div style="float:left">
  <b:Icon ui:field="selectedIcon" type="BAR_CHART_O" visible="false"></b:Icon>
</div>
<br style="clear:left" />
```